# How i get to know on which server, web application is running

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-server, central-administration, web-application

i have a sharepoint farm consists of 3 servers. I have different web apps deployed on that farm. I want to know on which server a specific web app is running? is there any way to know this through Central admin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically Web Applications run on the WFE server. Their are couple of ways to check it.

1. Check the Alternate Access Mapping
2. if you have the DNS for each web Application, then ping that DNS and it will give you the Ip of the server.
3. ALos from Central Admin > Manage Server in farm, check which server is running the Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application services. this should be your WFE..